# How to store image in Blob service with Azure function?

Tags: image, multipartform-data, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Let say I have very simple application to store image something like this

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const multipart = require('parse-multipart')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()

app.post('/images', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'multipart/form-data' }), (req, res) => {
  const parts = multipart.Parse(req.body, multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']));
  fs.writeFileSync(`./images/${parts[0].filename}`, parts[0].data)
  res.status(200).send()
})
```

Now I would like do same with Azure function to store image in Blob service. I have something like this

```
const multipart = require('parse-multipart')

module.exports = function (context, req) {
  const parts = multipart.Parse(req.body, multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']))
  context.bindings.blob = parts[0].data
  context.res = {
    status: 200
  }
  context.done()
}
```

blob binding is configured function.json. The image is stored and I can download it from portal, but the content is not correct.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Do you mean there is a problem with the actual image which is getting stored or is there an issue with the content type of image when it is downloaded

Comment: Can you post an example of the blob you're uploading and an example of the contents after you put it in blob storage?

Comment: I think the issue is that multipart is not working with Azure functions. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2009